# PhpStorm can't find xdebug WAMP server

Tags: wamp, phpstorm, xdebug

I am running a WAMP local server and I set up xdebug exactly as the [wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php) told me to. I edited the `php.ini` file that you get when you right click on the WAMP icon (the one in the Apache directory) but according to PhpStorm XDebug is not installed.

Comment: 1) Screenshots please 2) Please also provide `phpinfo()` output.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by editing the php.ini file in both the php directory and the one that you get in the menu. So long as the XDebug portion is identical on both files, it works perfectly.